# I couldn't add variables in the argument

Tags: python, variables, pdf, arguments, watermark

The program is for watermarking pdfs by taking arguments from a user through command line
like( python watermarker.py wtr.pdf single.pdf twist.pdf super.pdf)

**error** : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonsaves\AndreiNeagoi\PROJECTS\PdfManager\watermarker.py", line 9, in 
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter(open(str(mark), 'rb'))
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

***Code -***

```
 import PyPDF2
import sys

inputs = sys.argv[2:]
mark = sys.argv[1]


watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter(open(mark, 'rb'))
marker = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

def Marker(watermark, pdf_list):
    for j in range(template.getNumPages()):
        page = template.getPage(j)
        page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
        marker.addPage(page)

        with open('watermaked_output.pdf', 'wb') as file:
            marker.write(file)


for i in range(inputs):
    template = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter(open( inputs[i], 'rb'))

    Marker(watermark, template)
```

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html says the class is for writing pdfs, maybe you should just use it at the end for writing? Why not open the pdf using with ... as file?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the `__init__` function for `PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter` objects takes only one argument, which is `self`; that is, in your code you can only construct `PdfFileWriter` objects by calling, say, `instance=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()`, and then use functions `addPage` and `write` to construct and output the document.

Have a look here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html

Comment: The error you are getting ("TypeError: __init()__ takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given") clearly entails that the constructor of PdfFileWriter takes not other argument than self.